# Variable hoisting - "var" with global variable name in function

Tags: javascript, scope, hoisting

I was practicing some scenario and find a case:

[Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/S94e2/)

According to closure bar function should have access to `var x` so I expected to alert 1 and condition get false due to `if(!1)` but it alerted `undefined` and condition get true and second alert is with value 10.

```
var x = 1;
function bar() {
    alert(x);
    if (!x) {
        var x = 10;
    }
    alert(x);
}
bar();
```

So I am confused why it is prompting undefined?

According to hoisting in a particular scope you define a variable anywhere it is considered as defined at top always.

If it is due to hoisting effect it still have to alert 10 instead of undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hoisting causes a variable to be *declared* everywhere in the function, not defined.

On the first line of `bar`, since there is `var x` on line 3 of the function, the global `x` is masked and you see the local `x` (which is `undefined` since it hasn't been given a value yet).

On line 3 of `bar`, you have `x = 10` which defines the variable. This is not hoisted.

On line 5, you alert it, and it is now defined.

[image: Venn Diagram of the above]

Answer (score 1):

Hoisting will make your code effectively work like this:

```
var x;
x = 1;
function bar() {
    var x; //same as var x = undefined;
    alert(x);
    if (!x) {
        x = 10;
    }
    alert(x);
}
bar();
```